# How can I fill in a specific date where a field in a data frame has '1900-01-01' as a date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with a field named 'completed_date' and it has a bunch of dates that look like this: `'1900-01-01'`. How can I update all these dates to be `'2019-01-01'` only if the date is `'1900-01-01'`?

I tried this code.

```
df.loc[df['completed_date'] == '1900-01-01', 'completed_date'] = '2019-01-01'
```

I didn't get an error and it seemed to run fine, but when I look at the results, I still see a bunch of `'1900-01-01'` records in this field.  Maybe there is a Pandas solution for this.  Not sure.  Any thoughts?

Comment: what's `df.completed_date.dtype`?

Comment: if it's `object`, you can try the `str.replace()` method that Prune linked, though it's not clear to me why your current code didn't work (works for me locally).

Comment: The data type is object. I tried this: df.completed_date('1900-01-01', '2019-01-01')
I got this result: TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: That was a mistake; not I can't edit the comment.  Anyway...

The data type is object. I tried this: df['completed_date'] = df['completed_date'].replace('1900-01-01', '2019-01-01')

Nothing was updated. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your dates have leading/trailing spaces. Try: `df['completed_date'] = df['completed_date'].str.strip().str.replace('1900-01-01', '2019-01-01')`

Comment: This ultimately worked for me: .astype(str).str.replace

So...df['completed_date'] = df['completed_date'].astype(str).str.replace('1900-01-01', '2019-01-01')

Comment: Thanks for a point in the right direction here!